# Temporary turn off Bailed Failed notifications

Tags: tfs

As a Team Foundation Server administrator I'm not able to turn off the Build Failed notifications. Is there a possibility to do that. The Build Notification is sent to the whole team. 
I've tried to turn of this message in my own personal Notification Settings. Also in the Team nofication settings and in the notification settings of the Default Collection (that's where my project belongs). 
The Build Failed Notification is greyed out for me. The only ability I have is to Turn Off the notification which I did. Unfortunately the Build Failed message will be sent when a build fails.

Can anyone assist me to turn off the build failed notification to the whole team?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly turn off the team notifications in **Project Settings--Notifications--Project team**

The sample screenshot from Azure DevOps/TFS server 2019 for your reference：
[image]

For collection level Notifications, you could choose to **disable** the subscription.

*Note:* This will effect any project in the collection.

[image]

Comment: I turned off the Build Failed and disabled the Build completes notifications. However my team and I still receive the emails when a build failed.

Comment: @MarcelBeeker Sounds really weird,  this is make sense,  others may still receive email  when a build failed, if you turned off the shared subscriptions. Whether you are an administrator or not, toggling a shared team subscription from your notification settings **only impacts you and not other team members.** However, you should not able to receive the notification. I have created a simple test in my environment, could not reproduce the issue. Could you add a screenshot with detail settings for your **team's ** and collection level notifications here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the reason which was responsible for sending the build failed mails. It was a subscribtion of which I thought is was disabled. Sorry for this question....